# Изменение всех foreign keys

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всех приветствую. Есть большое количество таблиц, и очень большое количество foreign key. Нужно их всех сделать `on delete cascade`. Боюсь руками это делать очень долго. Есть ли способ сделать это запросом? бд Mysql

Comment: А для всех ли ключей это нужно?

Comment: Получи данные по FK из INFORMATION_SCHEMA да обработай поштучно в рамках ХП, используя PREPARED STATEMENTS.